# What are the names of the different Bracing/Indenting styles in C/PHP/Java etc?

Tags: coding-style, indentation, curly-braces

In languages that use 'curly braces' for code blocks, and where whitespace isn't a concern (C, Java, PHP) - What are the names for the different bracing/indenting styles?

I remember reading about 'KNF' and 'Flag', but it'd be great to have the most recognized names, along with some simple examples of each.

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [Indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style):

> In computer programming, an indent
>   style is a convention governing the
>   indentation of blocks of code to
>   convey the program's structure. This
>   article largely addresses the C
>   programming language and its
>   descendants, but can be (and
>   frequently is) applied to most other
>   programming languages (especially
>   those in the curly bracket family).
>   Indent style is just one aspect of
>   programming style.